# Get Max date of each month

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to get the maximum date of each month from a database column using SQL Hive.
I have a table as below:

| yyyymmdd |
| --- |
| 2020-05-01 |
| 2020-05-10 |
| 2020-05-20 |
| 2020-05-27 |
| 2020-06-03 |
| 2020-06-12 |
| 2020-06-21 |
| 2020-06-23 |

I tried this code:
`SELECT  MAX(yyyymmdd) OVER (PARTITION BY last_day(yyyymmdd)) as last_yyyymmdd FROM mytable t`

But I got this result:

| yyyymmdd | last_yyyymmdd |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-05-01 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-05-10 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-05-20 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-05-27 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-06-03 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-06-12 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-06-21 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-06-23 | 2020-06-23 |

Results I am expecting:

| yyyymmdd | last_yyyymmdd |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-05-01 | 2020-05-27 |
| 2020-05-10 | 2020-05-27 |
| 2020-05-20 | 2020-05-27 |
| 2020-05-27 | 2020-05-27 |
| 2020-06-03 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-06-12 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-06-21 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-06-23 | 2020-06-23 |

Answer (score 0):

one posibilty would be GROUPing the data by year and month and joining it to the table

```
SELECT [yyyymmdd], MAX_MONTH
  FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN
(SELECT format([yyyymmdd],'MM.yyyy') AS  year_month, MAX([yyyymmdd]) MAX_MONTH
FROM Table1
GROUP BY format([yyyymmdd],'MM.yyyy') ) t2 ON t2.year_month = format(t1.[yyyymmdd],'MM.yyyy')
```

| yyyymmdd | MAX_MONTH |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-05-01 | 2020-05-27 |
| 2020-05-10 | 2020-05-27 |
| 2020-05-20 | 2020-05-27 |
| 2020-05-27 | 2020-05-27 |
| 2020-06-03 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-06-12 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-06-21 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-06-23 | 2020-06-23 |

an equal partion can you use, if you prefer window functions

```
SELECT [yyyymmdd]
  , MAX(yyyymmdd) OVER (PARTITION BY format([yyyymmdd],'MM.yyyy')) as last_yyyymmdd FROM Table1 t
```

| yyyymmdd | last_yyyymmdd |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-05-01 | 2020-05-27 |
| 2020-05-10 | 2020-05-27 |
| 2020-05-20 | 2020-05-27 |
| 2020-05-27 | 2020-05-27 |
| 2020-06-03 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-06-12 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-06-21 | 2020-06-23 |
| 2020-06-23 | 2020-06-23 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/79MfT_Md)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
with temp1 as
(
select month(yyyymmdd) monthnumber, max(yyyymmdd) maxdate from Table1
group by month(yyyymmdd)),
temp2 as
(
  select yyyymmdd, month(yyyymmdd) monthnumber from Table1
)
select yyyymmdd, yyyymmdd
from temp1
join
temp2
on
temp1.monthnumber = temp2.monthnumber
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/GM6laIkI

Answer (score 0):

The query you provided is right assuming yyyymmdd is type `date`.

```
SELECT yyyymmdd,  MAX(yyyymmdd) OVER (PARTITION BY last_day(yyyymmdd)) as last_yyyymmdd FROM mytable t.
```

[image: See test on hive 2.3]